# QueryDSL: How to write expression to find difference of dates in seconds?

Tags: java, mysql, querydsl

I have a db table in which I have two date columns a and b. I want to write a query which involves computing the time difference of these two dates.

Right now what I am doing is

```
Expressions.operation(Integer.class, Ops.SUB, qMyDAO.firstDate.second(),
                        qMyDAO.secondDate.second())
```

But this isn't giving me the correct results. How can I pass the correct value of this time difference? What is wrong with my expression? Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using `querydsl-sql`? If so, the `SQLExpressions` class provides the [`datediff`](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/latest/apidocs/com/querydsl/sql/SQLExpressions.html#datediff-com.querydsl.sql.DatePart-com.querydsl.core.types.dsl.DateExpression-D-) method, which I think meets your requirements.